# Can a variable be locked to prevent changes to it in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, constants

I am using a member variable and at some point of the program I want to change it, but i prefer to "lock it" everywhere else to prevent unintended changes.

Code to explain:

```
class myClass {
    int x;  // This should be prevented to being changed most of the time
    int y;  // Regular variable
    myclass() {x = 1;}
    void foo1 () {x++; y++;} // This can change x
    void foo2 () {x--; y--;} // This shouldn't be able to change x
                             // I want it to throw a compile error
};
```

The question is: Can it be achieved in some way? Something like permanent const_cast?

I know I could use constructor initialization list and constant right away, but i need to change my variable later.

Comment: make it private, and only change it when you want to?

Comment: You want to prevent the implementation from changing x, or do you want to prevent anyone from calling the method?

Comment: @Joe: I want to throw it an error at compile.

Comment: `void foo2 () const {x--;}`

Comment: @Joe: According to msdn "A constant member function cannot modify any data members or call any member functions that aren't constant" therefore it does not solve my problem. I need foo2 to change other data members.

Comment: You are writing the implementation so don't change `x`.

Comment: @Petr: Please edit that into the question, because you oversimplified the problem, and will not get the answers you're looking for.

Comment: why is `foo2` modifying x at all, if u dont want it to?

Comment: @Joe: it's not that confusing, he wants a compiler error if he accidentally changes a particular member variable that should not have been changed in a particular member function.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Edited. I did not realized that I simplified it that much.

Comment: Code it correctly and write unit tests. Otherwise you will need to declare all other variables as `mutable` which I would not recommend.

Comment: @Petr: No problem, it's impossible to know how much to simplify the question unless you already know the answer, so it's completely understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, all the other answers I dislike, so here's my idea: hide the variable.

```
#define READONLY(TYPE, VAR) const TYPE& VAR = this->VAR //C++03
#define READONLY(VARIABLE) const auto& VARIABLE = this->VARIABLE //C++11

class myClass {
    int x;  // This should be prevented to being changed most of the time
    int y;  // Regular variable
    myClass() :x(1), y(2) {}
    void foo1 () {// This can change x
        x++; 
        y++;
    } 
    void foo2 () {// This shouldn't be able to change x
        READONLY(x); //in this function, x is read-only
        x++; //error: increment of read-only variable 'x'
        y++;
    } 
};
```

There are still ways to bypass the locking of the variable (such as `this->x`), but nothing can be done for those situations.

Comment: Seems to me if you're going to do this, you want something like `#define lock(v) const auto &v = this->v`, so in the function it shows up as `lock(x); /* ... */`. A template might let you do the same more cleanly.

Comment: That is elegant solution if I want to prevent editing in just one function, but can I prevent it in general?

Comment: @Petr: There's no way to generalize that even in theory.  In the question you had comments to tell _us_ which variables are locked in which functions.  The compiler will need that same general sort of information.  Its easy to make it not editable in _any_ function, but if it's editable in some, you have to tell us/the compiler which functions.

Comment: A mistake in C++11 version - not `const auto& x` but `const auto& VARIABLE`. Anyway - easy to break - just do `this->x++`...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: I considered that, but I've now put it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
class myClass {
    int x;
    mutable int y;
public:
    myclass() : x(1) {}
    void foo1 () {x++; y++}      // this can change x or y
    void foo2 () const { y--; }  // this can't change x by can change y
};
```

If you mark a member function `const` like this, you can't do anything in that member that would modify a member of the object (unless that member is `mutable` or `static` -- and `static` isn't really a member of an object at all).

Note that this won't simply prevent you from calling a function that attempts to do such modification -- rather, a function that's marked `const` but tries to modify the object state won't compile at all.

I should add, however, that I'm not at all convinced that this is really the best design. Rather the contrary, it sounds to me like your requirements on `x` and `y` are sufficiently complex that they would probably make more sense as separate classes that enforce the proper constraints directly (e.g., by providing an overload for `operator=` that only accepts input under the correct circumstances).

In other words, the use of `mutable` I've shown above is (I think) the simplest and most direct answer to the question you've asked, *but* it seems fairly probable that you're not really asking the question you should, and you're more likely to benefit from changing the design -- unfortunately, you haven't told us enough about the "big picture" to suggest what the better design might be.

Comment: `mutable`?  I think I would have dropped the `const` idea and gone with hiding the variable personally.  Or unit tests or something.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It's the most direct answer to what he's asking. I suppose I should add a bit of warning though.

Comment: Well, it is a good idea, unfortuantely it would imply, that al regular variables would have to be mutable, and all regular functions would have to be const, right? And I feel it is not a good idea to write it like that.

Comment: @Petr: Yes, as I said in the answer, I *think* what you need is a different design -- but don't know enough to be sure what that design should be.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure it is worth your effort, anyway, just in case this is quiz or sth, try to combine private inheritance with friend:

```
class MyClassX {
protected:
  MyClassX() : x(1) {}
  int x;
public:
  int getX() const { return x; } // read only access
};
class MyClassY {
protected:
  MyClassY() : y(0) {}
  int y;
  friend class MyClass;
public:
  int getY() const { return y; }
};
class MyClassXY : private MyClassX, private MyClassY {
public:
    void foo1 () {x++; y++}      // this can change x or y
};
MyClass : public MyClassXY {
public:
    void foo2 () const { y--; }  // this can't change x but can change y
};
```

Comment: Not a test, but simply my curiosity.

Comment: @Petr - I did not try my solution, let me know if it is something to fix. According to my best knowledge it should meet your constraints.

Comment: @Petr (+1) for curiosity, I always believe this is good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Make `x` a `private` member of a `subClass`, and make `foo1` a friend function of the `subClass`. Like this:

```
class myClass {
    int y;  // Regular variable
    myClass() : x (1) {}
    void foo1 () {x.x++; y++;} // This can change x
    void foo2 () {x.x--; y--;} // This shouldn't be able to change x
                            // I want it to throw a compile error
    class subClass {
      friend void myClass::foo1() ; // This must come after the declaration of foo1
      int x ; // private
    public:
      subClass (int x) : x (x) { }
      int read_x() const { return x ; }
      } x ;
};
```

This throws a compiler error, just where you wanted it.

Comment: I got confused since you never use `read_x`, but you're right: http://ideone.com/JTkfSq

Comment: @Mooing Duck: What use is a write-only variable?

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot do what your are trying to do...
Somebody correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: He wants `foo1` to change x, but not `foo2`

Comment: @benjarobin: the variables can be locked by hiding them

Comment: @Mooing Duck: But if I hide it (whatever that means), could I use it for read only purpose somewhere else?

Comment: @Petr: yes, if it's only hidden in the one function.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the answer is no, as long the class can see the variable and it's not constant - it can modify it.
But you could accomplish what you want by decoupling the variable you want locked into a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with a private x variable.  In it write your method.

Derive from this class your actual class.  Make the x holder a friend of the actual class.

X holder uses CRTP like casting (static cast to base) in the x holder to turn this into a pointer to your actual class.

Expose an x getter from your x holder.

I would not bother myself, but this is better than abusing mutable and const.